# Common storage for EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I wanted to attach a EC2 volume to multiple EC2 instance and create a common directory for all my scripts.  I was not able to do this.

Is it possible to mount some shared storage between all my EC2 instances to keep common files like scripts?  Can I use S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use S3 for this, or you could have a single instance will all the files in, and then push (rsync for example) these files to the locations you want them- you would only have 1 set of files to keep up-to-date then.

Comment: Can you mount S3 against an amazon instance?

Comment: Take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [nfs share](http://www.migrate2cloud.com/blog/how-to-setup-nfs-server-on-aws-ec2) on an instance.